# python requests 400 error

Tags: python, python-requests, amazon-mws

Hi I am using python requests module. My code is:

```
import requests

payload = {'AWSAccessKeyId':'AKIAJHSXAECVML4XJT7NvVLAQ',
      'Action':'ListOrders',
      'CreatedAfter':'2015-05-31T18%3A30%3A00Z',
      'MarketplaceId':'A21TJRUUN4KGV',
      'SellerId':'A3AZITEDAVC4SLU02M7',
      'SignatureMethod':'HmacSHA256',
      'SignatureVersion':2,
      'Timestamp':'2015-06-03T10%3A13%3A48Z',
      'Version':'2013-09-01'}

response = requests.post('https://mws.amazonservices.in/Orders/2013-09-01', params=payload)

print response.status_code
```

*These are Fake credentials*

I get this :
400 
What I am i doing wring?

Comment: Status code is returned by server(not by client lib), isn't it?

Comment: The exact error is *400 Client Error Bad Request*. I used another method with same credentials. I get this error. On using python  requests i get the above error

Comment: Are you sure that request hasn't been sent to server? Usually requests raises error if something wrong on its side. Error looks like typical response from server on malformed request.
Btw, probably you should use data instead of params(if you have to send json). Params creates GET parameters, but you're trying to send POST request - that's why I think so

Comment: I dont know. I am trying to access the amazon mws api via requests. On scratchpad it says post method so i used requests.post. It returns data in xml format. So what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this Third party tool called [TEMBOO](https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Amazon/Marketplace/Orders/GetOrder/) who provides API SDKs for many websites and there is a SKD for Amazon AWS in Python and when i downloaded it and checked the code for ListOrders.py i found these code below which makes it clear that it's expecting date in ISO 8601 date format (i.e. 2012-01-01).

```
super(ListOrdersInputSet, self)._set_input('AWSSecretKeyId', value)
def set_CreatedAfter(self, value):
"""
Set the value of the CreatedAfter input for this Choreo. ((optional, date) A date used for selecting orders created after (or at) a specified time, in ISO 8601 date format (i.e. 2012-01-01). Defaults to today's date if not provided.)
```